# Passing request parameter to View - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Is it possible to pass a `route` parameter to a controller to then pass to a view in `laravel`?

Example;

I have the route below;

```
Route::get('post/{id}/{name}', 'BlogController@post')->name('blog-post');
```

I want to pass `{id}` and `{name}` to my view so in my controller

```
class BlogController extends Controller
{
    //
     public function post () {

     //get id and name and pass it to the view

        return view('pages.blog.post');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
public function post ($id, $name) 
{
   return view('pages.blog.post', ['name' => $name, 'id' => $id]);
}
```

or even shorter:

```
public function post ($id, $name) 
{
   return view('pages.blog.post', compact('name', 'id'));
}
```

**EDIT** If you need to return it as JSON you can simply do:

```
public function post ($id, $name) 
{
   return view('pages.blog.post', ['json' => json_encode(compact('name', 'id'))]);
}
```

Comment: In my view I can view echo out the data this way `{{$name}}`. How can I pass this to `JavaScript`? Or apply `json_encode` to it

Comment: You can simple pass it to JavaScript putting value for example `<script>var = {{$name}}</script>` or you can use `<span id="name">{{$name}}</span>` and using JavaScript get value of element with `id='name'`

Comment: When I do `var = {{$name}}` I get an error thrown by my IDE `expression expected`.. Normally I would just do `<?php echo $name ?>` for example but I'm using `blade` which doesnt support such

Comment: @moh.ABK Sorry of course it should be `<script>var name = '{{$name}}'</script>`

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work?

```
class BlogController extends Controller
{
    //
     public function post ($id, $name) {

     //get id and name and pass it to the view

        return view('pages.blog.post', ['name' => $name, 'id' => $id]);
    }
}
```