# How to add query string to Laravel view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.7 and would like to return a view, with query strings. E.g. below is what I'm doing right now.

```
return view('cart', compact('somevar'))
```

This takes the user to `mydomain.com/cart`

I'd like to add query strings, e.g. so the user goes to `mydomain.com/cart?id=123`

How would I do this?

Comment: Just create the url from you are redirecting to this screen and use $request->id to get the querystring value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing request parameter to View - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34483859/passing-request-parameter-to-view-laravel)

Comment: This is not a duplicate he already knows how to pass to parameters. He is asking something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this :

```
return view('cart', ['id' => $id]);
```

Your data should be an array with a key-value pair.

You can also use `with` method:

```
return view('cart')->with('id', $id);
```

Also, you can use `compact` :

```
return view('cart', compact('id'));
```

For more, please refer [Passing Data To Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#passing-data-to-views)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to view like this:

```
return view('admin-panel.leave.index')->with($data);
```

And $data is an array that contain multiple values like this:

```
  $data = array('count' => '7', 'id' => '4');
```

Answer (score 0):

What your asking is not doable with this approach.Because, the main problem is `/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View` does not have what you are looking for. Only way to do that is `return redirect()->route('cart', ['id' => 123]);`

If this is really necessary, I think you need to redirect before call the `/cart` Something like this to your `rootes/web`:

```
Route::get('/addcart', 'CartsController@workaround');
Route::get('/cart', 'CartsController@showtheview')->name('cart');
```

Then in your **CartsController**:

```
public function workaround(){
  // your code.....
   return redirect()->route('cart', ['id' => 1]);   
}
public function showtheview(){
  //your code....
  return view('cart', compact('somevar'))
}
```

Hope you get the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. All the answers here forget that "somevar" has to be returned as well. Not only somevar compact data must be returned, but the URL must have variables too.

Put otherwise, you want internal blade data by compacting, but the URL must look different because it must have "&somevar2=xyz&somevar3=abc" appended.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but not possible.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this :

```
Route::get('cart/{id}', 'TicketsController@edit');
```

And in return:

```
return view('cart/'.$id, compact('somevar'))
```

Also you can try like this:

```
// app/Http/routes.php
Route::get('/cart/{id}', function ($id) {
    return view('cart')->with('id', $id);
});

// resources/views/example.blade.php
The last part of the route URI is <b>{{ $id }}</b>
```